# react native can not use boolean value in component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm using a simple demo to learn react native, I found a strange thing.

This is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {success: false}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js.
          {this.state.success}        //this line can not be shown
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I use set a state in the `constructor()` but can not access it in `render()`, and when I set the `success` value to a string or int, it will display.

Is anything wrong in my code ? why can not I use boolean ?

Comment: By default, boolean values are not shown in React. Why do you need to display a boolean value?

Comment: What will you expect to see? String `false`?

Comment: `undefined` or `null` won't display either, btw. You can use this property for conditional rendering.

Comment: I think it should be seen as a string `false` as @MikhailShabrikov said.

Comment: Just use toString() as @Chris mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing it alright, but nothing is shown because it is a boolean, not a string or number.

If you want to display a literal "true" or "false" you should convert it to a string first with `toString()`:

```
<Text style={styles.instructions}>
  To get started, edit App.js.
  {this.state.success.toString()}
</Text>
```

---

If I remember correctly, I read that they decided not to render boolean values in order to support more flexible in-line conditionals.

Short-circuit evaluation is one such example:

```
{!this.state.success && <p>Whoops, something went wrong!</p>}
```

If `success` is true, the message above won't be rendered. In vanilla JS however, this would return the string literal "false" - not ideal when, like in the example, you want to either render *something or nothing*.

Imagine how annoying it would be if you rendered the return value of some object method (i.e `indexOf()`, `map()`,  etc) and react rendered the string literal for *undefined*, *null*, and other falsy values. This doesn't happen; instead, React renders nothing.

Some more info from the official documentation [**here**](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored):

> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are valid children. They simply don’t render. These JSX expressions will all render to the same thing: